how to set color only for the current selection effect?
Now I have selected the edge object through the interface, but I want to set the color of the selected effect.
The edge object has a display method, but after this method is set, the selected object is still highlighted after the selection disappears, and this method needs to be called again to eliminate the highlighting.
here is the code i select the edge object:
Entity entity = (Entity)edge;
entity.Select4(true, swSelData);

I just want to set the color of the currently selected effect instead of the selected object always changing to the color I set.
Add red color to the edge:
edge.Display(20, 1, 0, 0, true);

remove the color:
edge.Display(0, 0, 0, 0, false);

I find SelectionMgr.SelectionColor can set the color, but not work:
int mark = swSelectionMgr.GetSelectedObjectMark(0);
swSelectionMgr.ClearSelectionColors();
swSelectionMgr.SelectionColor[mark] = (int)swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swSystemColorsSelectedItem3;

I got the code to set the color of the selected object from the macro recording, it modify the setting of selection colors:
swApp.SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue(swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swSystemColorsSelectedItem1, 2987775)


What do you mean by "effect"?

@solidWorking, highlight selection effect
